# How to make UITextView register touches when it is currently first responder?

Tags: ios, touch, uitextview, tap, first-responder

I need a way to know when a UITextView is touched while it is first responder.  I have seen some threads about this but I have never figured out how to make it work.  I'm assuming there must be a way?  Any input would be much appreciated thanks!

rc

Answer (score 1):

`UITextField` is a subclass of `UIControl`, so you can add yourself as listener for events using [`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget%3aaction%3aforControlEvents%3a).